# Jquery Lightbox Close On Form Submission

Tags: jquery, location, colorbox

I'm using JQuery Colorbox for several elements on my website, including the Login Form.  I'm submitting the form using JQuery Post and everything wirks fine with that, except I can't redirect my users back to the parent window after the form has been successfully completed.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
// Submit button action
$('#formButton').click(function()
{
var logusername=$("#logusername").val();
var logpassword=$("#logpassword").val();
var logcheckbox = ( $("#logcheckbox").is(":checked") ) ? "checked" : "not checked";

if(logusernameok == 1 && logpasswordok == 1)
{           
    $('.validation').html("").removeClass("validationError").removeClass("validationSuccess").addClass("validationSending");
    jQuery.post("php/login.php", {
    username:logusername,
    password:logpassword,
    checked:logcheckbox
    },  function(data, textStatus){
    if(data == 1){
        window.location.replace("events.php");
    }
    else{
        $('.validation').html("").removeClass("validationSuccess").removeClass("validationSending").addClass("validationError");
    }
    });
}
```

Can anyone suggest what to use instead of "window.location.replace("");"?

Comment: why do you use window.parent? AFAIK this is only needed in a child window (e.g. real Popup window).

Comment: The form is in a lightbox popup - What should I use instead?

Comment: window.location.href = 'main-page.php' i guess...

Comment: I tried that to begin with and it prevents the form from being submitted

Comment: maybe you can post a little bit more code (your form, submit function, html..) to clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an event listener on the form like this:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  var logusername=$("#logusername").val();
  var logpassword=$("#logpassword").val();
  var logcheckbox = ( $("#logcheckbox").is(":checked") ) ? "checked" : "not checked";

  if(logusernameok == 1 && logpasswordok == 1)
  {           
    $('.validation').html("").removeClass("validationError").removeClass("validationSuccess").addClass("validationSending");
    jQuery.post("php/login.php", {
    username:logusername,
    password:logpassword,
    checked:logcheckbox
    },  function(data, textStatus){
    if(data == 1){
        window.navigate("events.php");
    }
    else{
        $('.validation').html("").removeClass("validationSuccess").removeClass("validationSending").addClass("validationError");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either - I tried combining my original codes together and it's now working using this - `window.parent.location.replace("home-page.php");`